# Lack of congruence in mathematical abilities versus writing abilities in faculty

Tags: research-process, mathematics, united-states, humanities, responsibilities

Because of my background in mathematics and statistics, I have been called upon by my department (the Math/Stat Department) to assist faculty members from the humanities and linguistics departments in performing routine statistical analyses for a few of their publications. While the actual statistical analysis is very low level (basic undergraduate statistics), I am of course more than happy to do the simple work and be given co-authorship on a paper.

However, in the course of performing these statistical tasks, I have found that some of these professors do not even know how to perform *elementary* tasks such as finding the average of a set of numbers, adding fractions with single digit denominators, or calculating 45 cubed ("There's no button for that on the calculator!"). These are all tasks that I literally knew how to do when I was in elementary school. It did not take a PhD in math to know how to do these things (or even a high school diploma).

Because of this, I have begun to wonder why we seem to be completely fine with supposedly  "well-educated" (is that too harsh?) people being entirely incompetent at mathematics. Some of these people that I am asked to help have what I would deem to be 2nd or 3rd grade math skills. What if I, as a math researcher, only *wrote* on a 2nd or 3rd grade level and had to call upon the English department to write my papers for me?  Or what if I could not even identify who painted the Mona Lisa (or that such a painting even existed)?

**Should I suggest that my university begin encouraging 'non-math' faculty to become more competent in core mathematics?**

I am not saying that these professors are charlatans and do not deserve their faculty positions. They are very knowledgeable on the specifics of their topic. And I am not trying to berate people for whom math is not their strongest subject. However, I wonder if there are steps that the academic community could begin to implement that would enforce a higher standard of competence in basic mathematics among "non-math" faculty.

Comment: I'm not sure this venue is the best for this type of question, but I am highly sympathetic to your concerns.

Comment: Worth noting that STEM researchers with very poor writing skills also exist and present the same dilemma.

Comment: This is very difficult to correct. One reason is that the failure of the educational system occurred for many people at many different times and in many different ways. It isn't that they are dumb. They don't have the background, nor the time to develop it. If you were failed in the 3rd grade and never brought up to speed it is an almost impossible task to fill in the gaps. The fact that the can excel in other fields shows they have mental ability, it is just undeveloped and hence dormant in areas that you are comfortable with.

Comment: "perform elementary tasks such as finding the average of a set of numbers, adding fractions with single digit denominators, or calculating 45 cubed" ... are you trying to get them to do this in R, with a calculator, on paper, what?

Comment: @AzorAhai As in, they hand me a basic +-*/ calculator and say "This calculator cannot calculate 45 cubed." They do not understand that 45 cubed is 45 times 45 times 45.

Comment: Writing "well educated" in quotes when talking about university professors is not "too harsh". It's arrogant on your part, defaming, and degrading. These people didn't get a PhD and a faculty position by accident. How would you react if someone questioned the quality of your education when you make spelling mistakes or display ignorance of historic events, for example? I for one would be furious. (And before anyone starts, I'm a mathematician.)

Comment: In any case, I don't see how this question is about academia. You could ask the same about any other profession, and I wouldn't see the difference. There's no expectation that academics in particular are knowledgeable beyond their field of expertise.

Comment: @user2357 I am not suggesting that they need to be competent in my subject to the level that *I am*. I am suggesting that perhaps someone is not well educated if they cannot do 3rd grade math. I don't speak or write on a third grade level. I'm not sure anyone would point to a college professor who spoke on a 3rd grade level and say "Wow, he's really well educated."

Comment: And you single out math because...?

Comment: @user2357 "Because of my background in mathematics and statistics"

Comment: I was looking for a good reason.

Comment: @user2357 Vladhagen singles out math because it is the subject he teaches. That's the reason. I have also found this to be an issue among the elementary education students I teach math to. Some of them are atrocious at math (can't add fractions, don't understand negative numbers, can't find the area of a square......). Yet we look the other way and give them teaching licenses. For whatever reason, it's considered okay to be really bad at math and still consider yourself educated.

Comment: @DC541 You missed my point. There's no reason to single out math. If Vladhagen decrees that someone cannot be considered "well-educated" without knowing basic math, then other basic skills (writing, history, biology... anything that's taught in school, essentially) should be tested and "encouraged". And now you see how absurd this gets. Or you can admit that you view math as superior to the rest?

Comment: @user2357 I am competent in 3rd grade math, history, biology, spelling, English, Spanish, Korean, botany, physical education, art, literature, etc. I'm not asking for *collegiate-level* competence. I single out math because that is my subject. I don't speak with the humanities professors about genetics or history or spelling. It's not my field. Hence my not speaking to it. But, to be plain, if a person cannot pass 3rd grade math, history, biology, spelling, English, Spanish, Korean, botany, physical education, art, literature, etc., I'm not sure we could say they are well educated.

Comment: @Vladhagen And did your university test you for 3rd grade literature before giving you your job? Do they have programs to encourage you to read children's books? How would you feel if they did? (It's like I'm talking to a wall.)

Comment: @user2357 Funny you should ask. We actually **did** have a short discussion on a book called *The Troll Under the Bridge*. It is a wonderful story about chasing your dreams and finding a purpose in life.

Comment: Okay. Have a good night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing is part of your everyday life and an essential job skill, as a STEM academic. The comparison between your writing skills and the basic math skills of a humanities professor is only valid to the extent that these math skills matter for the humanities professor's job. By all means, if their mathematical inability is hindering their research or teaching, they should brush up. But frankly, I trust them to make that call, and to seek out the many resources that are already available for that purpose, if necessary. If they need "encouragement" to do this, I question whether it would be all that helpful. You could teach them to add fractions, but if they didn't use it regularly, they'd forget again. If your only reason for why they should know math is that you as a STEM academic know how to write, I think it's a stretch. It would be like a physical education professor coming to the math department and saying "I remember geometry, why can't all of you lift weights?"

Comment: I'm also not calling the physical education professor over to my office to help me lift a stack of three math books.

Comment: @Vladhagen - but you seem happy to go over and do their math for them, so why shouldn't they let you? I haven't used my quantum mechanics in a long time, but I do know who to call to get the right answer quickly.

Comment: I'm going to just guess that many academics in the English department are a bit appalled at the writing of STEM academics. Ditto for philosophers at the thinking of STEM academics, etc. Don't assume superiority too easily.

Comment: We _think_ we can write, but I'll note that almost all of our writing is directed at people just like us. That is a much easier task than writing so that _anyone_ could understand.